# Dictionary comprehensions in python are too comprehensive

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Using python2.7 I found a weird time execution case:

```
data = dict( zip( a[0].split( ':' ), a[1].split( ':' ) ) )

data = { name: value for name, value in zip(a[0].split( ':' ), a[1].split( ':' )) }
```

Those two calls seems absolutely the same to me, however, I found that the dictionary comprehension version is about 4% faster - not too much, but very stable.

Is this true, and if so, why? Or is it just my imagination?

Comment: So how many items are there here? Looking up the global name `dict()` takes time too, if there are only 2 items in the `zip()` result that could trump the loop cost in the dictionary comprehension.

Comment: In other words, without knowing how many items you produced your test is pretty much meaningless. Stick to fixed, known inputs rather than use `zip()` and `str.split()` if you really want to compare.

Comment: Your generator produces values just **once**, but the `timeit` tests are run 1000 times. The first time the generator produces key-value pairs, the rest of the tests empty dictionaries are produced.

Comment: I'm reverting your edit however; in future, please ask a *new question* rather than update your existing post with new questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , yes, you are right about questions, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your input sample is too small. Looking up the global name `dict()` takes more time than just running the dict comprehension (the latter doesn't require name lookups), but if you test against a *large* number of key-value pairs `dict()` wins as the looping is done entirely in C.

Test the difference against a *large* number of key-value pairs, and reduce the test to just the `dict()` call or the dictionary comprehension (the `zip()` and `str.split()` calls are executed just once for both cases and can be ignored):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import random
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> kv_pairs = [(''.join(random.sample(ascii_lowercase, random.randint(10, 20))), ''.join(random.sample(ascii_lowercase, random.randint(10, 20))))
...             for _ in xrange(10000)]
>>> len(dict(kv_pairs))  # the random keys happen to be all unique.
10000
>>> timeit('{k: v for k, v in kv_pairs}', 'from __main__ import kv_pairs', number=1000)
1.3174479007720947
>>> timeit('dict(kv_pairs)', 'from __main__ import kv_pairs', number=1000)
0.6737580299377441
>>> timeit('{k: v for k, v in kv_pairs}', 'from __main__ import kv_pairs; kv_pairs = kv_pairs[:3]')
0.511167049407959
>>> timeit('dict(kv_pairs)', 'from __main__ import kv_pairs; kv_pairs = kv_pairs[:3]')
0.6696300506591797
```

So for 10k key-value pairs (first two timing tests), `dict()` is twice as fast, for just 3 pairs (second two timings), the dict comprehension wins.

You can see why when you decompile the bytecode; the dictionary comprehension uses a nested code object to implement the actual dictionary building:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('{k: v for k, v in kv_pairs}', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <dictcomp> at 0x102ef69b0, file "", line 1>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (kv_pairs)
              9 GET_ITER            
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             13 POP_TOP             
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             17 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(compile('{k: v for k, v in kv_pairs}', '', 'exec').co_consts[0])
  1           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                21 (to 30)
              9 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (k)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (v)
             18 LOAD_FAST                2 (v)
             21 LOAD_FAST                1 (k)
             24 MAP_ADD                  2
             27 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   30 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(compile('dict(kv_pairs)', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (dict)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (kv_pairs)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

By using a very small sample, you gave the `LOAD_NAME` step for `dict` too much weight; the dict comprehension involves much more bytecode, executed each iteration.

Comment: What does `co_consts[0]` contains? A code object but where does it come from? Does it correspond to the `MAKE_FUNCTION` above?

Comment: @JeromeJ: dict comprehensions (as well as generator expressions and set comprehensions, and in Python 3, list comprehensions) get their own scope. Under the hood that is implemented by executing their bytecode as a function; the first decompile shows that the `LOAD_CONST` loads the constant at index 0 and creates a function object from that (`MAKE_FUNCTION`), then calls that with `kv_pairs` as an iterable being passed in. On the codeobject created by the `compile` call you can find all constants created by the compiler in the `co_consts` tuple.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, my input is really small, about several items in each a[i]. I tried to increase it just to 10-15 elements and dict already won without any doubts.Actualy, I would not imagine that dict comprehensions are much different from dict() calls in its code. Do you know, is dict() still faster than dict comprehension in python3?

Comment: @DmitriiBorisevich: yes, is still be faster in Python 3 for already-produced key-value pairs. Use a dict comprehension when you need to use an expression for each key and / or value produced.