# Creating unique dataframes based on one with adding a value to the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with statistics by region. I would like to build several other city datasets based on this dataset. At the same time, when creating in each such set, I would like to add a column with the name of the city.

That is, from one data set, I would like to receive three.

I'll give you an example. Initial dataset:

```
df
date         name_region    
2022-01-01   California
2022-01-02   California
2022-01-03   California
```

Next, I have a list with cities:  `city_list = ['Los Angeles', 'San Diego', 'San Jose']`

As an output, I want to have 3 datasets (or more, depending on the number of items in the list):

```
df_city_1
date         name_region    city    
2022-01-01   California     Los Angeles
2022-01-02   California     Los Angeles
2022-01-03   California     Los Angeles
```

```
df_city_2
date         name_region    city    
2022-01-01   California     San Diego
2022-01-02   California     San Diego
2022-01-03   California     San Diego
```

```
df_city_3
date         name_region    city    
2022-01-01   California     San Jose
2022-01-02   California     San Jose
2022-01-03   California     San Jose
```

It would be ideal if, at the same time, the data set could be accessed by a key determined by an element in the list:

```
df_city['Los Angeles']
date         name_region    city    
2022-01-01   California     Los Angeles
2022-01-02   California     Los Angeles
2022-01-02   California     Los Angeles
```

How can I do that? I found only a way of this division into several data sets, when the original set already has information on the unique values of the column (in this case, the same cities), , but this does not suit me very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`dictionary comprehension`](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter6_comprehensions.html#dictionary-comprehensions), and add the column `city` each time using [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html).

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': {0: '2022-01-01', 1: '2022-01-02', 2: '2022-01-02'}, 
        'name_region': {0: 'California', 1: 'California', 2: 'California'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

city_list = ['Los Angeles', 'San Diego', 'San Jose']

# "df_city" as a `dict`
df_city = {city: df.assign(city=city) for city in city_list}

# accessing each `df` by key (i.e. a `list` element)
print(df_city['Los Angeles'])

         date name_region         city
0  2022-01-01  California  Los Angeles
1  2022-01-02  California  Los Angeles
2  2022-01-02  California  Los Angeles
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution:

```
dfs = [] 
for city in city_list:
    dfs.append(df.assign(city = city))

cities = dict(zip(city_list, dfs))
cities['Los Angeles']
```

Output:

```
         date name_region         city
0  2022-01-01  California  Los Angeles
1  2022-01-02  California  Los Angeles
2  2022-01-02  California  Los Angeles
```

---

@ouroboros1, to whom I thank, suggests a very nice way of shortening my code:

```
cities = dict(zip(city_list, [df.assign(city = city) for city in city_list]))
```

Comment: Using `dict(zip(...))` here would be beneficial if the list `dfs` somehow already "existsed". As is, this method uses two loops, when the end result can already be obtained in the first. Eg. I would suggest writing `cities = {}`, then `for city in city_list:` and inside the for loop: `cities[city] = df.assign(city = city)`. That would be the same as the dict comprehension I suggested, but with longer syntax. It can be useful, however, e.g. when conditions need to be added or something (let's say: a check for duplicates in `city_list` and how to deal with them).

Comment: Thanks, @ouroboros1, for having commented my solution! I understand your point, but it appears *not* having any impact on execution time: My solution: `491 µs ± 8.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)`; Your solution: `501 µs ± 14.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)`. Both solutions appear to be equally time efficient!

Comment: Very interesting! So, `dict(zip(...))` is in itself *way* faster than a dict comprehension: see [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30050481/18470692). So, if `dfs` already "existed", there would be no contest. With the need for the for loop, the gain in performance is apparently offset by the extra costs of `zip` (also on a very large set). Still, with that knowledge, your use of `dict` seems to me to be the pythonic way to go. Might I then suggest: `cities = dict(zip(city_list, [df.assign(city = city) for city in city_list]))` as a one-liner? Learning something new every day :).

Comment: Thanks, @ouroboros1! Your one-liner is top! Also learning something new every day :-)